# SQL Server FILESTREAM storage

Tags: sql-server-2008, filestream

If I have a SQL Server 2008 database that uses FILESTREAM and stores 10 terabytes of files.  Must all the files reside on the same physical box (requiring a 10+ terabyte server)?  Or can I store 1 terabyte on one server, another terabyte on a second server, and so on?  From what I have read it appears you can only store files on a single server (remote or local)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now, it seems to be limited to local disk volumes only :-(

See this article at Simple-Talk:  [An Introduction to SQL Server FileStream](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/)

Towards the end of the article, there's a section on **FILESTREAM Limitations** which has one point:

```
* FILESTREAM data can be stored only on local disk volumes
```

From what I've been reading, a SAN (Storage Area Network) could possibly be used for FILESTREAM storage, but not other forms of storage systems. For 10 TByte, I would assume you're planning on a SAN anyway, right?

Also see this other [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419546/sql-server-filestream-limitation) (and the answers for it) on the topic.